# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word_list' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I don't understand what I am doing wrong; I have to make a hangman game and it has to pull the random word from an inputted list. However, in my "rand_word" function, it says that I can referencing it before assignment? How is that possible?

```
import random

board = [
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n  |   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n /    |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n / \\  |   \n      |   \n========= \n'
]



class Hangman:
    def __init__(self,word):
                self.word = word  # depends on game mode; will either have user input word or will get word from word list
                self.missed_letters = []  # empty list is created to hold missed letters
                self.guessed_letters = []  # empty list is created to hold guessed letters

    def guess(self,letter):
            if letter in self.word and letter not in self.guessed_letters:  # if the letter is in the word, but not in the guessed letter list, add it
                    self.guessed_letters.append(letter)
            elif letter not in self.word and letter not in self.missed_letters: # if the letter is not in the word, but also not in the missed letter list, add it
                    self.missed_letters.append(letter)
            else:
                    return False
            return True

    def hangman_over(self):
            return self.hangman_won() or (len(self.missed_letters) == 6)  # checks to see if the game has been won or if there are 6 incorrect guesses

    def hangman_won(self): #function to determine if you won
            if '_' not in self.hide_word():
                    return True
            return False

    def hide_word(self): # keeps word "hide" until you guess correct letters
            rtn = ''
            for letter in self.word:
                    if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                            rtn += '_'
                    else:
                            rtn += letter
            return rtn

    def print_game_status(self):  # this function shows the hangman game board, letters guessed, and letters missed
            print(board[len(self.missed_letters)])
            print('Word: ' + self.hide_word())
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
            print('Letters Missed: '),
            for letter in self.missed_letters: #prints every missed letter
                    print(letter)
            print(' ')
            print('Letters Guessed: '),
            for letter in self.guessed_letters:
                    print (letter)



def rand_word():  # chooses random word with '5 or more letters' in word_list

        word_list = open(word_list.txt, 'r')
        for word in word_list:
                return word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list))]
        else:
                return False
        word_list.close()



def main():

    game = Hangman(rand_word())
    while not game.hangman_over():
            while True:
                    game.print_game_status()
                    user_input = input('\nEnter a letter: ')
                    if len(user_input) >= 2:
                            print("\nEnter only ONE letter at a time!\n")
                            try_again = input('Try again: ')
                    if len(try_again) == 1:
                            game.guessed.append(try_again)
                            break
                    else:
                            continue

    game.print_game_status()        
    if game.hangman_won():
            print('\nCongratulations! You win!')
    else:
            print('\nYOU LOST, THE GAME IS OVER')
            print('The word was ' + game.word)

    print('\nGoodbye!\n')




if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
word_list = open(word_list.txt, 'r')
```

You wrote `word_list.txt`, which looks to Python like you're trying to get the `txt` attribute of `word_list`.

Put the filename in quotes.

Incidentally, if you do this:

```
with open('word_list.txt') as word_list:
    ...
```

...then the file will close automatically at the end of the block, even if an exception is raised.